# Make keyboard toolbar background transparent

Tags: swiftui, uitoolbaritem

I have a NavigationLink inside a keyboard toolbar. Everything works fine, but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to make the toolbar background transparent.

This is my code:

```
Form {
   Section {
       TextField("Track Number", text: $tracknumber).focused($focusedField, equals: .tracknumber).font(.title)
           .toolbar {
               ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                   NavigationLink(destination: NewParcelSegue()) {
                       Text("Continue")
                   }.buttonStyle(PinkButtonStyle())
               }
           }.onAppear{UIToolbar.appearance().isTranslucent = true}
       
   } header: {
       Text("")
   }
}
```

I tried several solutions without success. How do I make the toolbar background .clear?

[image]